# excel vba 2013 run-time error 424 object required

Tags: vba, excel, object

Help.  This is driving me crazy. I have the following code:

```
private sub anything()
     ' 30 lines of code that work perfectly
     MsgBox myNotesFile.sheets("NotesReport").Cells(3, 6)  '1
     fixLongLines
end sub

Private Sub fixLongLines()
  MsgBox ""  '2 
  MsgBox myNotesFile.sheets("NotesReport").Cells(3, 6) '3
  MsgBox ThisWorkbook.sheets("bindata").Range("A1") '4
end sub
```

The first msgbox (1) works perfectly.  In the sub the first msgbox (2) works perfectly but the second one (3) (which is exactly the same as the one in the original sub) gives me the 424 error.

If I comment out the offending line the third msgbox (4) works perfectly.  'myNotesFile' is referenced without any problems prior to the code I've shown here.  And this sub works perfectly in another module.
Any suggestions as to why I am getting this error in this one location in my code?

Comment: What is myNotesFile?

Comment: Your second sub cannot figure out what the **myNotesFile** workbook variable refers to. Where is it declared and set?

Comment: Les, I see you are new to the site. You will get reputation points if you accept an answer. It is considered good form here to accept and vote answers that work for you so others who see this can know what your solution was.

Comment: When you get an error on a line with several different expressions, break the line into multiple lines introducing and using new variables to connect the expressions so that you can figure out which part of the expression is causing the error.  In this case, this would mean doing `set t1 = myNotesFile`, then `set t2 = t1.Sheets("NotesReport")`, then `set t3 = t2.Cells(3,6)`.  You'd be surprised what that tells you because often we're suspicious of the wrong part of the expression!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the comments states, fixLongLines doesn't know what myNotesFile is. You could pass your worksheet or just one sheet though a parameter to the fixLongLines. Here's how you would pass just one sheet:

```
Sub anything()
     ' 30 lines of code that work perfectly
     MsgBox myNotesFile.Sheets("NotesReport").Cells(3, 6)  '1
     Dim nr As Worksheet
     Set nr = myNotesFile.Sheets("NotesReport")
     Call fixLongLines(nr)
End Sub

Private Sub fixLongLines(mySheet As Worksheet)
     MsgBox ""  '2
     MsgBox mySheet.Cells(3, 6) '3
     MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Sheets("bindata").Range("A1") '4
End Sub
```

If you don't want to pass a parameter, another workaround could be to make your call in fixLongLines like this:

```
MsgBox Workbooks("myNotesFile.xls").Sheets("NotesReport").Cells(3, 6)
```

Of course, you'll need to change the extension if your file is not a .xls file.

Comment: myNotesFile is a workbook, properly (I believe) declared and opened and used many times without incidence prior to this error in the same subroutine.  I will try some of the suggestions and let you all know what happens.  The frustrating part is that I use this coding method in all my modules and this is the first time I have encountered this problem.  It has never been a problem before.

Answer (score 0):

I used Tony L's suggestion of declaring nr and passing it to the sub. It worked like a charm.  Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: I added another possible workaround in my answer that may work for you as well. Since the answer works for you, would you please accept it? There is a check mark to click on below voting area on the left.

Comment: Another possible solution if you don't want to pass the object or variables around is to Dim them outside of the sub up the top of the module, this makes it available to all routines in that module.